# Searching for a whole word that contains leading or trailing special characters like - and = using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to know a position of a string (word) in a sentence. I am using the function below. This function is working perfectly for most of the words but for this string `GLC-SX-MM=` in the sentence `I have a lot of GLC-SX-MM= in my inventory list` there is no way to get the match. I tryied scaping -  and = but not works. Any idea? I cannot split the sentence using spaces because sometimes I have composed words separated by space.

```
import re 

def get_start_end(self, sentence, key):
        r = re.compile(r'\b(%s)\b' % key, re.I)
        m = r.search(question)
        start = m.start()
        end = m.end()
        return start, end
```

Comment: what is `key` in your sample code?

Comment: Show the sample input and output so that someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the key when looking for a literal string, and make sure to use unambiguous `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` boundaries:

```
import re 

def get_start_end(self, sentence, key):
    r = re.compile(r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(key)), re.I)
    m = r.search(question)
    start = m.start()
    end = m.end()
    return start, end
```

The `r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(key))` will build a regex like `(?<!\w)abc\.def\=(?!\w)` out of `abc.def=` keyword, and `(?<!\w)` will fail any match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the keyword and `(?!\w)` will fail any match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actual answer but help to solve the problem.

You can get pattern dynamically to debug.

```
import re 

def get_start_end(sentence, key):
        r = re.compile(r'\b(%s)\b' % key, re.I)
        print(r.pattern)

sentence = "foo-bar is not foo=bar"

get_start_end(sentence, 'o-')
get_start_end(sentence, 'o=')

\b(o-)\b
\b(o=)\b
```

You can then try matching the pattern manually like using https://regex101.com/ if it matches.